# Dealing with properties, ivars, and custom accessor methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, properties, ivar

This question arose from [this Encapsulating Data guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

It is really bothering me, and I want to get some insights on it. On the section **You Can Implement Custom Accessor Methods**, the guide does this:

```
@property (readonly) NSString *fullName;
- (NSString *)fullName {
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}
```

Why create a property to do this? Isn't just the method enough? And more importantly: the property `fullName` is by default `atomic`. The getter completely desregards this.

It looks to me custom `getters/setters` are a terrible thing to do, because they bypass all the property's modifiers. But the guide goes and tells people to do it. What am I missing here?

Comment: To be correct, the accessors need to be written so that they obey the attribute declarations.  For the rest of it, I think it's mostly a coding style decision.  (Many programmers think of properties as providing access to data elements and methods as having more complex functionality but that's certainly not a rule.)

Comment: The problem is that it is not clear anywhere how to `obey the attribute declarations`. That is why the guide feels so misleading to me. I've tried looking into the compiler code, and it does some quite fancy things